# How to automatically install an SSL cert on an AWS ElasticBeanstalk running on Windows & .NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to automatically deploy a .NET/Windows based Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance with an SSL cert?

I already have the DNS for the domain in the SSL cert setup to point to the Beanstalk instance.

I can remote in and configure the server manually but I was wondering if there is a way to make it part of the deployment package (similar to what Windows Azure has).

If this isn't built in to Elastic Beanstalk, are there any hooks to run PowerShell scripts after deployment (or update) of my instance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Developer Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.managing.elb.html)  explains how to enable an SSL certificate for your Elastic Beanstalk environment.
The relevant part is:

> Controlling the HTTPS port
>
> Elastic Load Balancing supports the HTTPS/TLS protocol to enable
>   traffic encryption for client connections to the load balancer.
>   Connections from the load balancer to the EC2 instances are done using
>   plaintext. By default, the HTTPS port is turned off.
>
> To turn on the HTTPS port
>
> - Create and upload a certificate and key to the AWS Access and Identity Management (AWS IAM) service. The IAM service will store the
>     certificate and provide an Amazon Resource Name (ARN) for the SSL
>     certificate you've uploaded. For more information creating and
>     uploading certificates, see the [Managing Server Certificates](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ManagingServerCerts.html) section
>     of Using AWS Identity and Access Management.
> - Specify the HTTPS port by selecting a port from the HTTPS Listener Port drop-down list.
> - In the SSL Certificate ID text box, enter the Amazon Resources Name (ARN) of your SSL certificate (e.g.,
>     arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/abc/certs/build). Use the
>     SSL certificate that you created and uploaded in step 1. For
>     information on viewing the certificate's ARN, see [Verify the
>     Certificate Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/index.html?InstallCert.html) topic in the Creating and Uploading Server
>     Certificates section of the Using IAM Guide.

Comment: I'm guessing the load balancer then takes care of all the SSL and there is nothing to setup in IIS?

I'm in the process of trying this out but AMZN doesn't make it easy to upload the certificates.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The SSL certificate gets associated with the load balancer.  The certificate does not have to be installed onto the EC2 instance.

Comment: what about the `Single instance` environment?

Comment: Are there any free alternatives to this? My application is so far away from even considering load balancing